# Reading timeseries from multiple csv files in a folder: MATLAB

Tags: matlab, csv

I have a bunch of csv files in a folder in following format, I want to extract complete time series from each (the numeric part from line #17), identify duplicate record and merge them in a ascending order according to year and date. 
Specific csv file is accessible via google drive link below

```
    wnsnum  1           
    paroms  Waterhoogte                                                             
    loccod  HOEKVHLD                                                                
    locoms  Hoek van Holland                                                        
    rks_begdat  1993 07 09          
    rks_begtyd  00:00           
    rks_enddat  2014 31 12          
    rks_endtyd  23:50           
    begdat  begtyd  enddat  endtyd  rkssta
    1993 07 09  00:00   2007 31 12  23:50   D     
    2008 01 01  00:00   2009 30 12  23:50   G     
    2009 31 12  00:00   2009 31 12  23:50   O     
    2010 01 01  00:00   2011 17 06  18:40   G     
    2011 17 06  18:50   2011 18 06  18:50   O     
    2011 18 06  19:00   2014 31 12  23:50   G     
    datum   tijd    bpgcod  waarde  kwlcod
    1993 07 09  00:00       -70 0
    1993 07 09  00:10       -69 0
    1993 07 09  00:20       -68 0
    1993 07 09  00:30       -67 0
    1993 07 09  00:40       -68 0
    1993 07 09  00:50       -70 0
    1993 07 09  01:00       -69 0
    1993 07 09  01:10       -69 0
    1993 07 09  01:20       -68 0
    1993 07 09  01:30       -67 0
    1993 07 09  01:40       -65 0
    1993 07 09  01:50       -64 0
    1993 07 09  02:00       -62 0
    1993 07 09  02:10       -61 0
    1993 07 09  02:20       -61 0
    1993 07 09  02:30       -59 0
    1993 07 09  02:40       -58 0
    1993 07 09  02:50       -55 0
```

Now my code is working in a following way:

```
SL_files = dir(sprintf('%s%s%s',fullfile(dirName),'\','*.csv'));
for idx = 1:size(SL_files,1)
    disp(SL_files(idx,1).name)
    fid = fopen(sprintf('%s%s%s',fullfile(dirName),'\',SL_files(idx,1).name)); 
    data = textscan(fid, '%s %f %f %f %f %f %f', ...
      'Delimiter',',', 'MultipleDelimsAsOne',1,'headerlines',16);

    fclose(fid);
end
```

Now I could read the file. Now my problem is how to combine multiple files' data into one matrix and arrange them in a ascending order according to year and day values. Thanks!

Comment: I copied your data into a csv file and found no problem. Probably in your original file those blank spaces are not always "spaces". Could you upload your file?

Comment: It may help if you look at the argument `MultipleDelimsAsOne`. I can't produce your problem anyway.

Comment: I would suggest you look into the function `csvread()` https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/csvread.html. You can select the row where you want to start reading from, and the columns you want to extract as well.

Comment: Hi, I have uploaded my file in the foll. link: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0dsL6q3VxD0TVc5X1NGTVFZRzA

Answer (score 0):

I finally solve my problem. Here is the code:

```
numMat_All = [];
for idx = 1:size(SL_files,1)
    disp(SL_files(idx,1).name)
    fid = fopen(sprintf('%s%s%s',fullfile(dirName),'\',SL_files(idx,1).name)); 
    data = textscan(fid, '%s %f %f %f %f %f %f', ...
      'Delimiter',',', 'MultipleDelimsAsOne',1,'headerlines',16);
    fclose(fid);

    CharCell = data{1,1};
    result = regexprep(CharCell,'[\s;:]+',' ');
    numMat = cell2mat(cellfun(@str2num, result(:,1:end), 'UniformOutput', false));

    numMat_All = [numMat_All;numMat];
    data = []; CharCell = []; result = []; numMat = []; 
end

dt = datetime([numMat_All(:,1:5), repmat(0,length(numMat_All),1)]);
T = table(dt,numMat_All(:,[6:7]));    
T1 = sortrows(T,'dt');
```